# How to use SQL IN operator in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I want to use IN operator in LINQ. I have a SQL query like given below. How do i include the where criteria.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT     ServiceId, ServiceName, Rate
FROM         Service
WHERE     (ServiceId IN (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

**LINQ**

```
string serviceId = "(1,2,3,4,5,6)";

try
{
    using (var context = new DBEntities())
    {
        var query = (from c in context.Service
                     where c.ServiceId == serviceIds     //ServiceId is the primary key
                     select new
                     {
                        serviceId = c.ServiceId,
                        serviceName = c.ServiceName,
                        rate = c.Rate

                     }).ToList();

        GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Use a collection and the `.Contains()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use contains of a list, make `serviceId` a list or array

```
var serviceIds = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

try
{
    using (var context = new DBEntities())
    {
        var query = (from c in context.Service
                        where serviceIds.Contains(c.ServiceId)      //ServiceId is the primary key
                        select new
                        {
                            serviceId = c.ServiceId,
                            serviceName = c.ServiceName,
                            rate = c.Rate

                        }).ToList();

        GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaC. I got an error "Error 8 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: Thank you @MichaC once again for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

```
where serviceId.Contains(c.ServiceId)
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use Any, there may be some problems while using contains.

var serviceIds = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

```
try
{
    using (var context = new DBEntities())
    {
        var query = (from c in context.Service
                        where serviceIds.Any(t=> t.ID == c.ServiceId)
                        select new
                        {
                            serviceId = c.ServiceId,
                            serviceName = c.ServiceName,
                            rate = c.Rate

                        }).ToList();

        GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```